# How does position.set center a canvas image ?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

Hey guys i was just going through this three.js example **[HERE](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html)** and after playing around with the example for sometime , i saw the below function:

```
// NOTE :: the below function, helps in positioning the 5 static red dots 
            function updateHUDSprites () {

                var width = window.innerWidth / 2;
                var height = window.innerHeight / 2;

                var material = spriteTL.material;

                var imageWidth = material.map.image.width / 2;
                var imageHeight = material.map.image.height / 2;

                // NOTE :: the below lines, helps in positioning the 5 static red dots 
                spriteTL.position.set( - width + imageWidth,   height - imageHeight, 1 ); // top left
                spriteTR.position.set(   width - imageWidth,   height - imageHeight, 1 ); // top right
                spriteBL.position.set( - width + imageWidth, - height + imageHeight, 1 ); // bottom left
                spriteBR.position.set(   width - imageWidth, - height + imageHeight, 1 ); // bottom right
                spriteC.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ); // center

            }
```

This function is basically helping position all the 5 pngs , i have played around with the above code quite a bit , but i still don't understand how the centering works , for example the below line:

```
spriteC.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ); // center
```

By playing around with the example a bit , i realized that the above line of code was actually positioning the center image , i just don't understand the values being passed to the position.set() function. if somebody could just explain how does `spriteC.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );` actually center the image , it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how camera is positioned

sprites are rendered using the orthographic camera `renderer.render( sceneOrtho, cameraOrtho );` and it has position `(0,0,10)`, looking at the origin `(0,0,0)`

anything at the origin or along a line parallel with z axis (our sprite with `(0,0,1)`) will appear to be in the center, negative `x` coordinate will move the object to the left, positive to the right and same thing with `y`